# How can I understand linear model result that dummy variable is included?

Tags: r, regression, categorical-encoding

```
Call:
lm(formula = Survival_Length ~ ., data = data_Len_Pro)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-252.19  -81.88  -19.02   65.09 2657.03 

Coefficients: (2 not defined because of singularities)
                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)             -64.05397  149.94256  -0.427 0.669243    
Service_Army1             6.86014    1.94917   3.520 0.000433 ***
Service_AirForce1       -30.64630    4.70418  -6.515 7.36e-11 ***
Service_Navy1           -36.71621    4.16287  -8.820  < 2e-16 ***
Service_Marine1                NA         NA      NA       NA    
Dead_in_VietSouth1       90.23008   82.12832   1.099 0.271928    
Dead_in_VietNorth1       32.92029   82.33041   0.400 0.689265    
Dead_in_Laos1            62.11062   82.56268   0.752 0.451884    
Dead_by_Hostile1        -11.78848    2.33658  -5.045 4.55e-07 ***
Grade_Officer1          -11.44643    4.80780  -2.381 0.017279 *  
Grade_Enlist1            16.53173    5.77596   2.862 0.004210 ** 
Dead_Reason_Vehicle1     17.31701    4.41061   3.926 8.64e-05 ***
Dead_Reason_Explosion1   -7.93170    2.24474  -3.533 0.000411 ***
Aircraft_Casualty1       -1.84331    4.68683  -0.393 0.694103    
Race_Caucasian1          16.42264   12.25704   1.340 0.180300    
Race_Negro1               5.58970   12.33875   0.453 0.650537    
Race_Indian1             13.17666   15.08574   0.873 0.382422    
Race_Malayan1             9.46053   14.90716   0.635 0.525673    
Married1                -26.93482    1.43888 -18.719  < 2e-16 ***
Single1                        NA         NA      NA       NA    
Sex.Man.1                 0.26008   43.90547   0.006 0.995274    
Type_Regular1            43.67495   12.80731   3.410 0.000650 ***
Type_Reserve1            25.91156   13.18200   1.966 0.049342 *  
Type_Temporary.Y.1       32.64072   12.84430   2.541 0.011049 *  
Corp_11                -120.10942   67.02313  -1.792 0.073131 .  
Corp_21                  56.12609   82.14028   0.683 0.494424    
Corp_31                  32.79214    3.51202   9.337  < 2e-16 ***
Corp_41                  33.08491    3.02721  10.929  < 2e-16 ***
PROCD_11                 -9.70704  115.96996  -0.084 0.933293    
PROCD_21                -21.05414  115.93940  -0.182 0.855901    
Province_M11            147.89131   67.04643   2.206 0.027403 *  
Province_M21            -10.09613   82.15070  -0.123 0.902189    
Province_M31              0.33561    3.32038   0.101 0.919490    
Length_of_Service         2.48028    0.08585  28.891  < 2e-16 ***
Age                       2.37115    0.15172  15.628  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 115.9 on 42615 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.06135,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.06065 
F-statistic: 87.04 on 32 and 42615 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Here is the result that I got from my data

most independent variables are categorical variables and just few variables
are continuous variable(x)

dependent variable is continuous variable(y)

in my dataset, for example, I transformed Service Type(Army, Navy, AirForce, Marine) to dummy Variable(Service_Army column, Service_Navy ...)
and gave 1 or 0 to each columns row.

What I want to know through this result is this.

Which variable are strongly related to the dependent variable??

when I looked at result table, I thought that Service types were related to

the dependent variable but Service_Marine column indicated NA. (Single cloumn also)

I found that NA happened when column had relation with other column, like 
column C = xA + yB + z

in this case, can I insist that Service type is strongly related to the dependent variable even though that is NA in the result table?

should all dummy variable columns indicate *** to say that columns are related to the dependent variable?? if not, is it okay one column indicate NA?

Answer (score 1):

> Which variable are strongly related to the dependent variable??

Independent variables with low p-values (denoted by asterisks in the model summary) are said to have a significant impact on the dependent variable. For example, a variable with a p-value below 0.05 (but exceeding 0.01) is said to be significant at the 5% level and is denoted with an asterisk in the model summary.

> the dependent variable but Service_Marine column indicated NA. (Single
>   cloumn also)

`Service_Marine1` and `Single1` are not defined because they are [perfectly collinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity) (with the other `Service_` variables and `Married1`, respectively). In the example of `Married1` and `Single1`, every observation is either one or the other. Therefore, when Married1 is equal to `0`, you know that the person is single. In general, when including dummy variables for a categorical variable, you should **include dummies for all but one of the outcomes**.

> in this case, can I insist that Service type is strongly related to
>   the dependent variable even though that is NA in the result table?

Based on the results, it does appear that service type is strongly correlated with `Survival_Length`. The `NA` in the model summary should not impact the result because it was not estimated, so removing the `Service_Marine1` and `Single1` variables will not affect the results.

Answer (score 1):

When encoding categorical variables as dummy variables you create several new variables to replace an existing multi-leveled factor.  In your example `Service Type(Army, Navy, AirForce, Marine) can become several variables (one for each service type) each with a 1 or 0 indicating if it is present for that record or not.

### Dummy Variable Trap

In your example `Service Type(Army, Navy, AirForce, Marine)` has become four variables `Service_Army1`, `Service_Navy1` `Service_AirForce1` `Service_Marine1`. In this case not all four variables are required. Using any three, the last one can be fully determined. For instance if the first three variables all have the value of zero, the 4th variable will obviously be 1. By including all four (as you point out) can cause problems with fitting and interpreting some models.  You can see in your example `Coefficients: (2 not defined because of singularities)` which relate to the variables with `NA` coefficients.

### Interpretation

The interpretation of a dummy variable is measure of the effect of that category relative to the *omitted* category.

### Further Reading

This answer may also help with interpretation: 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/165110/interpretation-of-dummy-coded-linear-regression

Comment: Service Type consists of 5 categories ; Army, Navy, AirForce, Marine, and Coast Guard. so (0, 0, 0, 0) means Coast Guard factor. but, as it is described above,  Service_Marine1 indicates NA.
Briefly, 3 result(Service_Army,Airforce,Navy)'s p-value is lower then 0.05 but Service_Marine1 indicates NA. in this case, can I insist that Service Type is strongly related to the dependent variable Survival Length?